# Given error when trying to iterate through an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I am making a Reddit bot using PRAW and the code gives me the error that the exception is not iterable. Here is a simplification of my code:

```
try:
  #something with praw that isn't relevant
except Exception as e: #this except error catches the APIexception, APIexpections in PRAW are a wide field of exceptions that dont't always have the same solution, so I scan the text for the error I'm looking for.
  print(e)
  if "keyword thats in the error" in e:
    #fix the problem with the specific error
  else:
    print("Unkown APIExpection error")
```

This works fine for me, but when I run this code:

```
try:
  #something
except Exception as e:
  for character in e:
    print(character)

#I also tried this

try:
  #something
except Exception as e:
  for character in str(e):
    print(character)

#None of the above work but this is my actual code and what I need to do, anything that gets the above to work should work here too, I'm just letting you know this so that I don't get any other errors I have to ask another question for.

try:
  #something
except Exception as e:
  characterNum = 0
  for character in e:
    characterNum += 1
    print(str(characterNum) + ": " + character)
```

It gives me a "TypeError: 'RedditAPIException' is not iterable", RedditAPIException can be ignore though as that's just the error I'm catching.

Comment: `print` converts the exception to a `str`.

Comment: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package_info/praw7_migration.html#id1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `for character in str(e):` approach should work, since then you're guaranteed to be iterating over a `str` rather than the actual `Exception`.  What error message do you get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the exception to string and then check in the if statement.

Change to => `if "keyword thats in the error" in str(e):`